# VBA - To split and excel file into multiple files and split those files into multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

The data is as follows

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWzNK.jpg]

I need to divide this data by two levels

1. Divide the data into different workbooks based on the first letter of the product code (column C) e.g. A.xlsx, B.xlsx etc. which would contain data related to only these letters
2. Divide the data in the above workbooks into worksheets based on the unique product code, e.g. C.xlsx will have sheets named C02, C021 and these sheets will contain the data pertaining to the procut code.

How can both of these be combined in a single VBA code?

I have the following code to split the data into sheets by the product code:

```
    Sub split_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 3
    Set ws = Sheets("Sales Data")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:H1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
    Next
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
```

```
End Sub
```

But now I need to combine all the sheets starting with A into a workbook "A.xlsx" and similarly for B,C and D. Need help in this

Comment: Could you inline your data as text in the description? The question is of no use without it and if the image is not accessible, this would render the question pointless.

Comment: Post what you've tried, and if you haven't tried anything, try now and then post back for help. You're more likely to get help that way than expecting someone to write all your code from scratch.

Comment: @SJR thanks for the suggestion. Have done the same

Comment: OK I think the way I would approach this would be to add a column with the first letter, use advanced filter to get a list of unique A,B,C etc and unique codes. Then you could use AutoFilter to extract each set of data into separate workbooks, and from there split each into constituent sheets. Does need a bit of thinking about.

Comment: @SJR Have to do it with VBA.

Comment: Yes, all that could be automated using VBA. You could probably google and find some code to do a lof that. I may have some code somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You'll need to change the file path and possibly sheet references

```
Sub x()

Dim rCell As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r2 = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Cells(1, r2.Columns.Count + 1) = "First"
    .Cells(2, r2.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(r2.Rows.Count - 1).Formula = "=LEFT(C2,1)"
    Sheets.Add().Name = "temp"
    r2.Columns(r2.Columns.Count + 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    For Each rCell In Sheets("temp").Range("A2", Sheets("temp").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=r2.Columns.Count + 1, Criteria1:=rCell
        Set ws1 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy ws1.Range("A1")
        ws1.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        With wb
            .Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(1)).Name = "Temp"
            .Sheets(1).Range("C1", .Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Sheets("Temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
            For Each r1 In .Sheets("Temp").Range("A2", .Sheets("Temp").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                .Sheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=r1
                Set ws2 = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
                .Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Copy ws2.Range("A1")
                ws2.Name = r1
                .Sheets(1).ShowAllData
            Next r1
            .Sheets("Temp").Delete
            .Sheets(1).Delete
            .Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="C:\" & rCell & ".xlsx"
        End With
    Next rCell
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets("temp").Delete
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```